# ¿Qué puedo utilizar para volver a un if sin utilizar un ciclo?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy realizando un programa utilizando programación en Python con la librería Tkinter. Quiero que mi interfaz gráfica vaya almacenando y calculando los valores que estoy dando, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, simplemente se reemplazan los datos. ¿Existe alguna manera de volver al if o algo parecido? Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as box
ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Ejercicio")
ventana.geometry("750x450")
ventana.configure(background = "white")

R = DoubleVar()
conexion = DoubleVar()
cont = IntVar()
Rq = DoubleVar()
def calcular():
    comercial = [100, 120, 150, 180, 220, 270, 330, 390, 470, 510, 560, 680, 820, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1800, 2200, 2700, 3300, 3900,
             4700, 5100, 5600, 6800, 8200]
    if R.get() not in comercial:
        box.showwarning("AVISO", "La resistencia ingresada no es comercial.")
    Rt = 0
    i = 0
    Rx = int(R.get())
    if conexion.get() == 1:
        Rt = Rt + Rx
        i = i + 1
        Rq.set(round(Rt, 4))
        cont.set(i)
    if conexion.get() == 2:
        Rn = 1E10
        Calc = 1 / (1/Rx + 1/Rn)
        Rt = Rt + Calc
        i = i + 1
        Rq.set(round(Rt, 4))
        cont.set(i)
#ENTRADAS
letrero0 = Label(ventana, text = "CÁLCULO DE RESISTENCIA EQUIVALENTE EN UN ARREGLO MIXTO", bg = "white", font = "Arial 14 bold")
letrero0.place(x = 50, y = 20, width = 650, height = 30)
letrero1 = Label(ventana, text = "Valor de resistencia", bg = "azure", font = "Arial 12 bold")
letrero1.place(x = 80, y = 80, width = 160, height = 30)
entrada1 = Entry(ventana, textvariable = R, bg = "white").place(x = 110, y = 115, width = 100, height = 30)
letrero2 = Label(ventana, text = "Tipo de conexión", bg = "azure", font = "Arial 12 bold").place(x = 80, y = 180, width = 180, height = 30)
Radiobutton(ventana, text = "Serie", bg = "white", variable = conexion, value = 1).place(x = 100, y = 220, width = 50, height = 30)
Radiobutton(ventana, text = "Paralelo", bg = "white", variable = conexion, value = 2).place(x = 100, y = 250, width = 70, height = 30)
letrero3 = Label(ventana, text = "Resistencias contadas:", bg = "azure", font = "Arial 12 bold")
letrero3.place(x = 80, y = 300, width = 180, height = 30)

#COMANDOS
boton1 = Button(ventana, text = "CALCULAR", bg = "green", command = calcular).place(x = 300, y = 250, width = 100, height = 30)
#SALIDAS
letrero4 = Label(ventana, text = "Resistencia Equivalente", bg = "azure", font = "Arial 12 bold")
letrero4.place(x = 450, y = 80, width = 200, height = 30)
salida1 = Label(ventana, textvariable = Rq, bg = "white").place(x = 460, y = 120, width = 190, height = 30)
salida2 = Label(ventana, textvariable = cont, bg = "white").place(x = 280, y =300, width = 50, height = 30)
letrero5 = Label(ventana, text = "Ω", bg = "white", font = "Arial 12").place(x = 600, y = 120, width = 20, height = 20)
letrero6 = Label(ventana, text = "Ω", bg = "white", font = "Arial 12").place(x = 330, y = 300, width = 20, height = 20)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Adjunta el código en formato de código, no en imagen. Así podremos copiar tu código y compilarlo en nuestras máquinas para ayudarte. No olvides pulsar en EDITAR todas las veces que quieras para modificar/mejorar tu pregunta!

Comment: Tu código no está correctamente indentado. En python la indentación (espaciado al inicio de las líneas) es lo que controla los bloques de código. Si no indentas las líneas que deberían estar dentro del método `calcular()` correctamente... ninguna línea está dentro de dicho método! No es posible que el código se ejecute bien si no está bien indentado para empezar.

Comment: Listo, ya debería poder copiarse el código sin problemas!